# How to use GPS with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, gps

I have a `Node.js` app where I would like to use the GPS information of the user.
I have never done that before in a web page or using javascript.

A little research on the net led me here:
    https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error

That seems to show that what I want to do is basically possible.

Nevertheless when I try to do something similar, I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
```

The relevant code is:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    // Do something useful with the location.
}
```

Obviously "navigator" is unknown whith Node.js.

Is there some good and simple example or tutorial showing how I can use the GPS within a Node.js app?

Comment: the "user" would send location to your server side nodejs app, perhaps - considering the nodejs code is run on a server that never moves, it's GPS location would me meaningless

Comment: No. Precisely speaking, I have a page displaying information with a GPS component, namely shops with their location. Inside the browser I want the user to see the shops ordered by distance, the closer at the top. You're right the server being fixed its GPS location is meaningless. What I want is using the user GPS location to determine which shop is closer to her/him. Sorry for my ambiguous formulation.

Comment: No? What do you mean no?

Comment: "No" answering to your question means: "No, this is not what I want." ... This is why I took the time to explain what I want, after writing "No".

Comment: oh, got it, I thought you meant you don't want the client side sending location to the server

Answer (score 2):

You could sent the data from the client using the geolocation API or use GeoIP via [node-geoip](https://github.com/bluesmoon/node-geoip) or [node-geoip-native](https://github.com/benlowry/node-geoip-native) and lookup their coordinates based on IP address. Here's an example implementation from `node-geoip`

```
var geoip = require('geoip-lite');

var ip = "207.97.227.239";
var geo = geoip.lookup(ip);

console.log(geo);
{ range: [ 3479297920, 3479301339 ],
  country: 'US',
  region: 'TX',
  city: 'San Antonio',
  ll: [ 29.4889, -98.3987 ],
  metro: 641,
  zip: 78218 }
```